# Trying to extract information in a regular expression

Tags: regex, data-extraction

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will allow me to extract the data in between the quotation marks, and then allow me to replace it with new information.

> title="Information here"

Comment: There is way too little information for us to help you. What are you going to use to process the regular expression? A tool (egrep, awk, sed), a language (Java, Perl, etc.)?

Comment: It's a new trend I suppose: letting SO guess the tool, ignoring that regex implementations are VERY different both in set of supported expressions and in ways of using them.

Answer (score 0):

```
(title=")([^"]*)(".*)
```

.* will match any characters

Then replace with

```
\1This is the new information\3

\2
```

will hold the extracted value

Comment: And how this regex will process this line: `title="Very long title" alt="Was there"`?

Comment: Erm. I actually meant `([^"]*)` there. Or just `(.*?)`.

Comment: ([^"]) makes more sense, what does .*? do (I've really just begun my Regex journey)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a language or tool that has a Regular Expression replace function.  This regex should match what you are trying to do:

```
^title="(.*)"$
```

Example of a regex replace:

```
preg_replace('^title=[\]?"(.*)[\]?"$','new information','title="information here"');
```

would replace "information here" with "new information"